# Flutter dio cannot see class Interceptor

Tags: flutter, interceptor, dio

I'm try to make custom interceptor but when I wrote this code:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class CustomInterceptors extends Interceptor {

}
```

Compiler throw error:

```
Cannot find name Interceptor
```

I was try to reload VSC, make:

```
flutter packages get
```

nothing work. I already install dio package and import it work but VSC don't see class Interceptor at all

Answer (score 0):

1. flutter clean
2. delete pubspec.lock
3. pub get

Comment: Still the same things after I did that

Comment: Solved after reload VSC it wokrt